# bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath: circle in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, physics, geometry, xcode6

im having some trouble with the bodyWithEdgeLoopFromPath: method in swift. i want to make a simple circle that acts as a border.
I found this http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10798 but its obj-c. any ideas ?

i also tried this piece of code

```
var path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 0, 0, 45, 0, M_PI*2, true);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

but i get the error 'init' is not convertible to 'CGFloat'

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are using takes CGFloats, so make sure you are passing those in. You can create CGFloats using `CGFloat()`, which can take a numeric literal and some numeric types.

```
var path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, CGFloat(0), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(45), CGFloat(0), CGFloat(M_PI*2), true);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

A look at the function definition shows which arguments need to be CGFloats.

```
func CGPathAddArc(path: CGMutablePath!, m: UnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool)
```

Comment: Please note that doing `CGFloat(45)` is not "converting" the 45 to a CGFloat, but it is initializing a new CGFloat with the initial value of 45. Subtle terminology difference but converting implies that you are treating the value as a different type.

Comment: That's a good point. I tried to emphasize the fact that it isn't casting, but converting does sound like it's modifying the value.

Comment: Ya, I've been struggling with what language to use there myself. I think "make sure you are passing CGFloats. To do so, you can initialize them explicitly." works.

Comment: I tried to make it a bit more clear. Thanks for the tip

Comment: did anyone ever caled you a hero ? i spend so much time to figure this out thanks!!! :d